# SimCity 4 Deluxe stopped working in Windows 7

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, simcity-4

I had SimCity 4 Deluxe installed and running on Windows 7 64-bit without any major issues for a few months. As far as I can remember, I do not think I even had to adjust compatibility mode, or tweak the command line launch options. Few days ago it worked fine, but yesterday I had tried to launch it, but it failed to start.

SimCity4.exe process appears in Task Manager, but only takes up 1.7-2.3 Mb of RAM and nothing happens (no error messages, no activity whatsoever). I checked Windows Event Log, as per suggestion in comments, it does not throw any errors. I suppose system does not deem it as an error since the process continues to run, and does not crash.

I had not install any new software recently, and latest Windows update was installed two and a half weeks ago, i.e. it could not contribute to the issue conceivably. The only thing I did differently game-wise is save on exit (before I would customarily save the game, or save and exit to region, and only then actually exit), but that would not break the installation, would it now?

Before I try reinstalling it, I would like to comprehend the mystery of what had transpired. Is that game files corruption issue? Is that some sort of system glitch? I would appreciate any input in answers or comments to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Have you tried repairing the install?

Comment: @Sorean There is no such option. Control panel only gives the option to uninstall the game. I had tried putting both the installation and play CDs.

Comment: I assume you have rebooted your computer since this started happening. Have you tried Right clicking on the icon and selecting "Run As Administrator"?

Comment: @Sorean Yes, rebooted several times. I ran it as admin (even though it was’t necessary before), and played around with different compatibility modes. I checked settings in other software that could interfere (anti-virus, Raptr etc.), did not see anything. I ran virus-scan, and Windows Defender, did not turn up anything.

Comment: Next step would be to check the Event log (eventvwr.msc in your startmenu) and see if the application is throwing out any errors when you start the game. You're looking under Windows logs, applications.

Comment: @Sorean Nope, nothing. I searched the log for errors during pust three weeks, the only things that show up in there are codes 1001 (Windows Error Reporting, but only when I tried to adjust compatibility settings, not on application launch), 9010 (Windows Desktop Manager, when the game CTDed), and once code 1000 (task category (100), Application Error two weeks ago). Other than those, nothing. The last time it CTDed was the last time I played, Oct 25.

Comment: By the way, when I try to launch it now, it does not even get to the point to ask for CD if I take it out. It just sits there, process stuck. That is probably why it does not throw any app errors, because for all intents and purposes it runs, not crashes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6263/discussion-between-theug-and-sorean)

Answer (score 1):

*Answer in Progress*

Issue is caused by Kaspersky Internet Security, which for some reason assigned High Restricted (based on heuristics) application control setting, and subsequently denied it for “code intrusion”. Manually assigning Trusted rating solves the problem.

Comment: I marked it as answer in progress, because it would be nice to find out why it did not have problems with SimCity for months, and then decided to change the app. control setting. Could be because of relatively frequent CTDs?